# HAProxy check/monitor multiple ports instead of one

Tags: haproxy

I've been searching the net and I can't find a good answer to my question, only how to bind multiple ports to inbound for the `Haproxy` but that's not what I need. I need to configure `Haproxy` on `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` to monitor/check multiple ports on the same host (MySQL, port 3306 and MySQL GROUP REPLICATION port 33061).

I've tried multiple set-ups and when I stop the mysql service, it works fine. However, when I stop MySQL GROUP REPLICATION, the HAProxy keeps directing traffic to that server

The current config I use:

```
#HAProxy for MYSQL
listen  haproxy_192.168.254.254_3307
        bind *:3307
        mode tcp
        timeout client  30s
        timeout server  30s
        balance roundrobin
        default-server port 3306 inter 2s downinter 5s rise 3 fall 2 slowstart 60s maxconn 64 maxqueue 128 weight 100
        server serv1 192.168.1.2:3306 check
        server serv2 192.168.1.3:3306 check

#HAProxy for MYSQL GROUP REPLICATION
listen  haproxy_192.168.254.254_3308
        bind *:3308
        mode tcp
        timeout client  30s
        timeout server  30s
        balance roundrobin
        default-server port 33061 inter 2s downinter 5s rise 3 fall 2 slowstart 60s maxconn 64 maxqueue 128 weight 100
        server serv1 192.168.1.2:33061 check
        server serv2 192.168.1.3:33061 check
```

I've checked the ports the server is listening on when I stop MySQL GROUP REPLICATION and at that moment, the server is no longer listening on port 33601. As said, the Haproxy is still directing traffic to that same server, which should be skipped as 1 out of 2 checks fails? But I can't get it to work properly

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [track](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#5.2-track) keyword for that in combination with [tcp-check connect](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4.2-tcp-check%20connect).

```
 listen  haproxy_192.168.254.254_3308
    bind *:3308
    mode tcp
    timeout client  30s
    timeout server  30s
    balance roundrobin
    default-server port 33061 inter 2s downinter 5s rise 3 fall 2 slowstart 60s maxconn 64 maxqueue 128 weight 100
    server serv1 192.168.1.2:33061 track mysql_tracker
    server serv2 192.168.1.3:33061 track mysql_tracker

  backend mysql_tracker
    option tcp-check
    tcp-check connect port 33061 further_paramters
    ... more tcp check stuff
    server serv1 192.168.1.2:33061 check
    server serv2 192.168.1.3:33061 check
```

Comment: Thanks, I’m going to test this today. Can you maybe explain why port 33061 requires those additional checks and port 3306 doesn’t? I’m curious as it’s both just a TCP check on a port number?

Comment: No as I don't use the mysql cluster. I just answer your question.

Comment: What I mean is that a port check on 33061 should be sufficient. If the cluster is up, the server is listening on port 33061. If the cluster is down, the server no longer listens to port 33061. However, the Haproxy doesn't seem to react on it. Is this perhaps because I use 2 listen interfaces in the Haproxy setup? Going to check your answer soon, should I leave the 3306 listen interface as is, since I need Haproxy to check/monitor both ports on the same machine?

Comment: well you can use for both listener the track so that only the mysql_tracker checks the cluster

Comment: Alright, but I can't specify the server name twice on a different port in one listen configuration? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: it's possible. But do you really think that so is the right place for such a discussion? There is a HAProxy mailing list where you can start such disscussion. https://www.haproxy.org/#tact

Comment: I think so as this seems to a common issue to me, but no good answer can be found on the internet...? I just simply want to use Haproxy to check both port 3306 and 33061 are up. If not, the server should be placed out of the list. As said, 3306 monitor works well, but 33061 doesn't work. When I stop the process that listens on port 33061, the Haproxy keeps the server online

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it working with the below listen-entry:

```
#HAProxy for MYSQL
listen  haproxy_192.168.254.254_3307
    bind *:3307
    tcp-check connect port 3306
    tcp-check connect port 33061
    server serv1 192.168.1.2:3306 check
    server serv2 192.168.1.3:3306 check
```

each `tcp-check` is evaluated and that's exactly what I needed. I want MySQL server to be marked down when any of the two ports (`3306` and `33061`) is down. Or when they both are down of course

Comment: +1, I was also looking into this and couldn't find a solution for it, this worked for me !. In my case I have a primary and secondary server am using the tcp-check for 4 ports , using the tag backup check for my secondary server, that way all traffic by default goes to primary , in case any one port down in primary whole traffic switched to secondary.